# Which software would be best to model these types of parts (needed for cubicle repair)?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I'm in need of printing some replacement parts for cubicles, and the image included with this post contains most of the parts we are need of replicating.

I read this [helpful infographic on different 3D software packages and their use cases for 3D printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9XyB.jpg) but am not sure which category these parts falls under. Would it be better to use Fusion360/OpenSCAD or Blender? We don't have the original measurements; we have the original parts and would be working off of pictures of the parts themselves.

[image: replacement cubicle parts]

Comment: I'd suggest just ordering replacement parts from the manufacturer, but knowing how obscenely expensive the panels are to begin with, I can't imagine what pricing is like on parts!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Recommendation questions are explicitly off topic. Your usecase however demands a CAD suite, you want to re-model the parts. You can take calipers and measure the parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In future, where should I post if am looking for recommendations? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Generally speaking, these "which product" questions aren't usually a good fit for stack exchange sites, and I'm loath to answer them. But I will say that Blender tends more towards artwork/sculpting-type models, and CAD products tend more towards engineered to specific measurements/tolerances -type models. This looks more like the latter. Also looking at these, I'd expect a better result on a resin printer. An FDM/filament printer should still be able to produce the shape, but I'm concerned about the strength of some of those fine clips.

Comment: Resin might be too brittle though. You might need to use an intermediate "molding" process to make it with a properly used plastic.

Answer (score 1):

You should use whichever software you're competent with. They will all do it.

Doing it from scratch without knowing the software is going to be a big learning curve. If thats the case you're probably best to use something like FreeCad as it's strength is in parts modelling.

Much more to it than just modelling the parts though, you need to be asking if these gadgets are actually suitable for 3d printing. Otherwise you can draw them, print them and then watch them fail.